# ReactNative Error {/F14Table.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler}

Tags: c++, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/kingsleyyong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lavaxProject-dascthkblhhdgeapnlketstfxkeq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/i386/F14Table.o /Users/kingsleyyong/React\ Learn\ Project/lavaxProject/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14Table.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I get this error when I first run my react native project in ios on my M1 mba.
Previously there have a lot of issues and I got rid of them but this issue is hard to solve.

> use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.91.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '~> 2.6', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '~> 1.4' })

this is my flipper ^^

When I used Xcode to run the project, it shows this error

```
/Users/kingsleyyong/React Learn Project/lavaxProject/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14Table.cpp:41:10: Thread-local storage is not supported for the current target
```

in F14Table.cpp file. Line 41 and line 56.

Need some help

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing this now too

Comment: sorry, I forgot how I solve this already, will look back at my code and let you know soon.

Comment: Any update for this case?